# Completion handler? async_dispatch?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, closures

These are the methods and processes which need to happen:

1. Download images from Parse
2. Download associated data (which matches images)
3. Plot this data on a map

Here is my code from view did load:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        imageDownload { () -> () in
            print("5-----inside closure")
            self.queryParseandSave(callback: self.plotImages)
        }
    }
```

Image download function:

```
func imageDownload(completed: @escaping FinishedDownload){
    print("1-----Started Image download")

    // Query for places
    let query = PFQuery(className:"ViewFinderObjects")
    query.whereKey("ImageVerified", equalTo: true)
    query.whereKey("coordinates", nearGeoPoint:myGeoPoint)
    query.limit = 10
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            for object in objects! {
                print("2-----inside object for block")
                    let imageFromParse = object["image"] as! PFFile
                    imageFromParse.getDataInBackground(block: {(imageData, error) -> Void in
                        print("Searching for Image")
                        if error == nil {
                            let obsImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                            self.imageToShow = obsImage
                            self.closestImage.append(self.imageToShow!)
                            print("There are \(self.closestImage.count) images in the image array")
                        }
                    })
                    print("3-----Completed object loop")
            }
        }

        print("4-----Calling completed statement")
        completed()
    }
}
```

Which then calls another function `queryParseandSave(callback: self.plotImages)`
with the `self.plotImages` plotting the images on a map.

I have 1 huge issue:

`self.plotImahes` is always called before the images have finished downloading

I have researched async_dispatch but have no idea if this is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the implementations of the `query.findObjectsInBackground` and `imageFromParse.getDataInBackground` methods, but their naming implies that they both happen asynchronously. Also judging from what you're provided above, the former retrieves the object data, while the latter does the actual image data download. If that is indeed the case, then it looks like you're calling your completion handler inside the body of the *first* asynchronous method instead of waiting for the second method (what appears to be the actual image download).

A couple of ideas for how to resolve this:

1. You could move your completion handler into the `imageFromParse.getDataInBackground` block, but this would only make sense if you're comfortable calling the completion block multiple times, after each image finishes downloading.
2. You could create your own dispatch or operation queue and wait until all tasks complete, *then* call the completion handler.
3. You could set up an observer or notification pattern that will call your completion handler at the appropriate time.

There are many different ways to address the issue, but the key thing to remember is that it sounds like you want to call your completion handler *after* all of the asynchronous operations have completed. Right now you're calling it after you've retrieved the objects, but all of your images are still downloading in the background when your completion handler is called.